# Pandas merge is not working, though data types of keys are the same

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, merge

I am using `pandas.merge` to join two dataframes based on two columns values. I checked the data types in both dataframes, and they are the same. Besides, for each of the two columns in both datasets I calculated the intersection between sets and it is definitely not empty. However, merge is not working properly and I just cannot find a reason for it.

I will post a piece of code here, though I don't have a minimum dataset to reproduce it, the data are too big. There are datasets `df` and `q0`, both of them have columns `permno` `date`, and I want to merge based on them.

```
# just to make sure the data types are the same
df['permno'] = df['permno'].astype(int)
q0['permno'] = q0['permno'].astype(int)

df['date'] = df['date'].dt.to_period('D')
q0['date'] = q0['date'].dt.to_period('D')

print(df.dtypes, q0.dtypes)
```

**Outpit for `q0`:**

```
date      period[D]
permno        int64
sum         float64
dtype: object
```

**Output for `df`:**

```
permno         int64
date       period[D]
sic            int64
prc          float64
...
```

Another step to make sure is to take the intersection between column values:

```
print(len(set(df.date.unique())&set(q0.date.unique())))
print(len(set(df.permno.unique())&set(q0.permno.unique())))
```

**Output:**

```
9154
5925
```

**Merge:**

```
df = pd.merge(df, q0, on=['permno', 'date'], how='inner')
print(len(df))
```

**Output:**

```
0
```

I tried it so many times but I can't figure out why it is not working now.

Comment: From the provided code one can see that you merge on 2 columns simultaneously. So you should perform `another step to make sure` like `len(set(zip(df.date.tolist(), df.permno.tolist())) & set(...))`.

Comment: I was so sure, I have overlap in the data, which I don't. Occasionally in the code I used `isnull()` instead of `notnull()`. Thanks for pointing that out!